# Invalid block tag expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Error trying to showing a ImageField

Tags: python, django, image, block, imagefield

im tryinh to use the ImageField from pillow library. And i have a problem with that.

When i try to show my image, i get the error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /home
Invalid block tag on line 62: 'articulo.nombre_imagen.url', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

this is my line 62:

```
<a href="article/id/{{articulo.id}}"><img class="card-img-top" img src="{% articulo.nombre_imagen.url %}" alt=""></a>
```

as you can use i am using the syntax correctly, well i supossed...

this is from my models.py:

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
return "static/img/" %(instance.id, filename)

class Articulo(models.Model):

nombre_imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
    null=True, blank=True, 
    width_field="width_field", 
    height_field="height_field")
width_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
height_field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: You are not closing a for or an if tag. Do check your template, as you have not shared the whole template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! if anyone wants to know the answer, i just add the function for i can show my actual image:

```
def preload_image(request, pk)
from .models import Articulo
from django.http import HttpResponse
from PIL import Image

articulo = get_object_or_404(Articulo, pk=pk)

img = Image.open(articulo.nombre_imagen.path)
response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/%s' % img.format)
img.save(response, img.format)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="image.%s"' % img.format
return response
```

In my urls.py i added the url:

```
url(r'^home', index, name='home'), it: url(r'^preload/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.preload_image, name='preload_image'),
```

And finally i modify my line to use it with the function:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{% url 'home:preload_image' pk=articulo.pk %}" alt="">
```

thanks a lot @Sergey Rùdnev !

Answer (score 1):

Try use `{{ }}` instead `{% %}`:

```
<a href="article/id/{{ articulo.id }}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ articulo.nombre_imagen.url }}" alt=""></a>
```

**UPDATE.**

In template:

```
<a href="article/id/{{ articulo.id }}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{% url 'preload_image' pk=articulo.pk %}" alt=""></a>
```

In views:

```
def preload_image(request, pk)
    from .models import Articulo
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from PIL import Image

    articulo = get_object_or_404(Articulo, pk=pk)

    img = Image.open(articulo.nombre_imagen.path)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/%s' % img.format)
    img.save(response, img.format)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="image.%s"' % img.format
    return response
```

Also insert that method `preload_image` to urls.py; and where `from .models` use your `from APPNAME.models`.

Comment: Now it works, but it doesn´t show the image. What could be?

Comment: Because your `articulo` it's only object, without method to show&response image. Update answer w/ example code.

Comment: I´m sorry, im noob at django. Could you help me?. How can i send the method in my url. My url from urls.py is like this: url(r'^home', index, name='home'), How can i include the preload_image on it? I´m sorry if i do too much questions :)

Comment: All okay. Just add after `url(r'^home', index, name='home'),` it: `url(r'^preload/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.preload_image, name='preload_image'),`

Comment: Ok, i just did that but i received the error "Invalid block tag on line 62: 'preload_image', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?" again.            this is my urls.py again so you can see: url(r'^home', index, name='home'),
    url(r'^preload/(?P<pk>\d+)$', preload_image, name='preload_image'),   i just include the new url in my urls.py

Comment: Oh, Luis. I'm sorry, I myself made a mistake (due to the fact that I did not sleep a day). So, i was edit my answer. in template (in tag <img>) u need change src to `{% url 'preload_image' pk=articulo.pk %}` and everything will be fine.

Comment: I have done that. but i received "NoReverseMatch at /home
Reverse for 'preload_image' not found. 'preload_image' is not a valid view function or pattern name." Because im not sending the preload_image to the function i think, i dont know :(